# Running R file through C# - Works with one file but not others

Tags: c#, r, ssis

I created simple code to execute an R file through C#. I need it to run for 3 R files, all of which produce a .txt file. The code works for one file, but not for the other 2. I have verified that the files are being picked up, and that they run for the expected amount of time, but the .txt files are not being produced.

```
static void Main()
{
    Process myProcess = new Process();
    try
    {
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.1\\bin\\Rscript.exe";  //enter filepath for Rscript.exe
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "c:\\users\\phaas\\documents\\greaterthanexceptions.r";  //enter desired .R filepath
        myProcess.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("R script failed: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you gave 3 different file paths in Arguments in the same process you are invoking?

Comment: Sumit, yes. I changed the file path for each .r file.

Comment: There is very little information here to give a possible solution. Can you reframe your question? Also have you checked running those R scripts manually and verifying they produce unique .txt file output.

Comment: Yes, they execute properly when run through R.

Comment: And when I run the C# code, it executes as expected with one out of 3 files (all of which run properly in R). They all are in the same directory, so the only difference in the C# code is the file name (all camel case and no symbols). And the R code is relatively simple and similar for all three.